# Can I set an IssuerSigningKey with Identity API Endpoints in a .NET 8 Web API using AddBearerToken?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, bearer-token, .net-8.0

I've developed a web API using the new [Identity API endpoints feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-7/#identity#identity-api-endpoints).

In my Next.js frontend, I've implemented protected pages, accessible only to authenticated users. To enable user access to these protected pages, I've created a verifyAuth function that validates tokens using a secret key:

```
export const verifyAuth = async (token: string) => {
  console.log("Token: ", token);

  try {
    const verified = await jwtVerify(
      token,
      new TextEncoder().encode(getJwtSecretKey())
    );

    return verified.payload as UserJwtPayload;
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error("Your token has expired. Please login again.");
  }
};
```

But to do this I have to sign the token with the secret key in my web api first.
If you're not using Identity API Endpoints, the signing process is straightforward, as shown [here](https://shahedbd.medium.com/net-7-web-api-jwt-authentication-and-role-based-authorization-f2ff81f69cd4) in the **Configure Identity and JWT** section, where you can set an **IssuerSigningKey**.

For those using Identity API Endpoints, a different approach is required. Instead of calling AddJwtBearer in your program.cs, you need to use **[AddBearerToken](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-7/#identity#bearer-token-authentication-handler#bearer-token-authentication-handler)**:

```
// Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddBearerToken();

// Authorization with Identity endpoints
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();
builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>();
```

The AddBearerToken method can take options, and I stumbled upon the **BearerTokenProtector** option in the Microsoft documentation. However, I'm uncertain about how to set a signing key within this context.

So, my question is, where should I set the IssuerSigningKey in this scenario? If my approach is flawed, what's the correct way to address this issue? Any guidance or corrections would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you solve this? Even though the API is protected, I can see that you'd still want to protect the pages. Do you just get a 401 and handle that?

Comment: In my frontend, I've implemented a middleware for my protected pages that specifically checks for the existence of an authentication cookie, without verifying its value. This approach is acceptable since the backend is responsible for handling the actual authentication process. In scenarios where a user, who has previously logged in to access a protected page, attempts to access another route after their token has expired, the backend responds with a 401 status code. 
As a result, my frontend intercepts the 401 status code and redirects the user to the login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token issued by the Identity API is not a JWT. It's a proprietary opaque token and you can't inspect it on the client side.
This token is meant for a first-party authentication/authorization scenario (client, server, and authentication are under your control), so the security context is slightly different from the third-party scenario

Comment: Does it mean, that I need to make a server call every time a user navigates to a protected page in order to validate the opaque token?

Comment: The token issued by ASP.NET Core Identity is an access token. It's meant to be used to access server's functionalities (typically API endpoints).
Why do you want to validate it on the client side?
As far as I understand, it should be validated on the server-side by the API  to be sure it's legitimate, but in this case you don't need to do so, because the ASP.NET Core Identity middleware does it for you

Comment: @AndreaChiarelli, with JWT I can achieve single-sign-on feature. Can I do the same with this new Identity access token (which is not a JWT)?

Comment: @AliShahzad, it's not JWT that lets you achieve single sign on. It's the specific protocol used for authentication and session management, such as SAML or OpenID Connect, for example.
In the API endpoints case, the token is meant for access management in first-party scenarios, so it's not meant for SSO

Comment: @AndreaChiarelli How can I use SSO then with Asp.Net 8 Identity? Please guide.